# jQuery, PHP & AJAX Issues

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email

So I've read the jQuery AJAX pages, and a bunch of tutorials, but am having a slight problem over here.

There are no errors, or warnings, just a blank page.

I am trying to send an email when the user fills in the newsletter subscription test field with their email address, and when you click submit, the page refreshes! (1st problem) and it fails to display anything on the page (second problem), all you see is just a blank page. No emails were received.

I've tested the email script separately, which works fine. I've been using for months with different sites so I know it works.

I've tried changing things around in jQuery etc but nothing has helped fix this problem.

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var txt = $('.email').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            email: txt
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (err, req) {
            $('#Response').html({
                "Somethin' got broked. Please try again."
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php


    if($_POST["email"] != null)
    {
        require_once "Mail.php";

        $email = $_POST["email"];

        // Send it.
        $from = "X@X.com.au";
        $to = $email;
        $subject = "Newsletter Subscription Request.";
        $body = "Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter!";
        $host = "mail.X.com.au";
        $username = "no-reply@X.com.au";
        $password = "X";
        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                    'To' => $to,
                    'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                    array ('host' => $host,
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password));
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
  <h4 id="Response">Stay informed. Subscribe to our Newsletter!</h4>
      <form class="newsletterForm" action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="email" name="email" />
        <input type='submit' class="btn" value="Subscribe" />
      </form>
```

Can someone please help me figure out why this won't work?

Thank you

Comment: Because you *don't* want a refresh. Got it.

Comment: Huh? I *don't* want it to refresh the page. - Ohhhh. That's what you meant..

Answer (score 2):

The 1st thing I do when stuff like this isn't working is to watch the page calls in the Chrome Developer Tools window.

As far as your code goes, the reason the page is refreshing is because the form submit is going through. To keep that from happening, you have to trap the form submit:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
        // Do ajax
        return false; // Keeps the form from submitting
    });
```

Once you have that in place, you should be getting better results.

I would caution, however, that it is much easier to get the PHP email sending form working *without* using ajax at first by just having it handle the regular form submit. Once that works, then tie in the ajax on top of it.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, but it still refreshes, and it still only displays a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

With the following line you suppose to receive an answer from the PHP Script

```
success: function(data) { 
            alert(data);  
}
```

But in the PHP script you don't output anything...Try writing something like

```
 //[...]
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                    array ('host' => $host,
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password));
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
        die(1);
```

Comment: yep so just try to echo something in the php script like "Mail Sent"

Comment: and as @cdeszaq said, you need to stop the submit of the form simply doing a return false; after the ajax function

Comment: Nothing happens still. It still doesn't even loadd the page after the form is submitted. It just displays a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

please try this surely you can get the problem solve.
 `function FormSubmit()
{ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'index.php',
        data: $("#form_main").serialize(),
          async: false
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $("#Response").hide();
            if (isNaN(data)) 
            {

                dispmsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Oops..Something had gone wrong! Please try again!</div>";
                $("#assess_me_response").html(dispmsg);
                setTimeout('ResetForm();',3000);
        }
            else
            {
                dispmsg = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Thank you for sharing the details. Our Consultant will contact you shortly!</div>";
                $("#assess_me_response").html(dispmsg);
                setTimeout('Redirect();',3000);
            }
            return true;
        });
}`

make your php as this..

```
<?php
$to = "xxxx@some.com";  

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];   
$subject = "Entry received";                                        

$msg = "\n Name:" . $name . "\n Email id:" . $email ."\n Age:". $age . "\n Contact number: " . $phone;      
$headers = "From:xxx@yyy.com";
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
echo "<div align='center'>Thank you " . $name . "!, we will contact you shortly.</div>";  
?>
```

try this you can solve.